# Unable to sent mail using exim4.8 - Unrouteable Address

Tags: rhel, exim

I am unable to send mails using exim4.8. Please find the below logs and my exim config file. Please help! Tried all config changes but not able to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the eximgrep result:

```
exigrep "xyz" /var/spool/exim/log/mainlog

2013-07-19 17:43:01 1V09YT-0006vZ-Ax <= root@192.168.4.14 U=root P=local S=419
2013-07-19 17:43:01 1V09YT-0006vZ-Ax ** yyy@yyy.yyy: Unrouteable address
2013-07-19 17:43:01 1V09YT-0006vZ-Ax Completed
```

Below is my Exim config file:

```
primary_hostname = 192.168.4.14

domainlist local_domains = @:localhost
domainlist relay_to_domains = *
hostlist   relay_from_hosts = 127.0.0.1

acl_smtp_rcpt = acl_check_rcpt
acl_smtp_data = acl_check_data
rfc1413_hosts = *
rfc1413_query_timeout = 5s



ignore_bounce_errors_after = 1d

timeout_frozen_after = 7d

begin acl

  deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
          domains       = +local_domains
          local_parts   = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|]


  deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
          domains       = !+local_domains
          local_parts   = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!] : ^.*/\\.\\./
  accept  local_parts   = postmaster
          domains       = +local_domains

  require verify        = sender

  accept  hosts         = +relay_from_hosts
          control       = submission
          control       = dkim_disable_verify


  accept  authenticated = *
          control       = submission
          control       = dkim_disable_verify

  require message = relay not permitted
          domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains

  require verify = recipient

$dnslist_domain\n$dnslist_text
$dnslist_domain
  accept

acl_check_data:

  accept


begin routers
smart_route:
driver=manualroute
transport=remote_smtp

route_data=bamail2.nova.local
no_more
system_aliases:
  driver = redirect
  allow_fail
  allow_defer
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/aliases}}
# user = exim
  file_transport = address_file
  pipe_transport = address_pipe


userforward:
  driver = redirect
  check_local_user
  file = $home/.forward
  no_verify
  no_expn
  check_ancestor
  file_transport = address_file
  pipe_transport = address_pipe
  reply_transport = address_reply

localuser:
  driver = accept
  check_local_user
  transport = local_delivery
  cannot_route_message = Unknown user

begin transports


remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp

  interface = 10.50.50.41

address_pipe:
  driver = pipe
  return_output


address_file:
  driver = appendfile
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add

address_reply:
  driver = autoreply

begin retry

*                      *           F,2h,15m; G,16h,1h,1.5; F,4d,6h

begin rewrite


begin authenticators
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the MX record of the domain.

> dig domain.com MX

if this is local MX, then make sure that its listed in the /etc/localdomains
In case if it is remote MX, then make sure that the domain listed in /etc/remotedomains

You better run the following scripts.

> /scripts/updateuserdomains
>
> /scripts/mailperm